# Implementing GARCH on Python for Index Hedging

Tags: python, package

I am trying to use GARCH(1,1) to find the hedge ratio as described in this paper http://search.livjm.ac.uk/AFE/AFE_docs/cibef0402.pdf. However, Python does not offer packages for GARCH(1,1), thus I think I have to implement it myself.

The data I have for the Index and the Futures are their daily returns. I would like to write a function that takes in the daily returns and output the beta of GARCH as the hedging ratio. However, I am at loss where to start writing the GARCH function. Could anyone outline step-by-step the algorithm for GARCH(1,1) in this case?

Comment: This question is off topic due to requesting a library or tool and should be closed, but can't be so due to the bounty. That said an example snippet is avaliable [here](https://gist.github.com/mdengler/2411139) and another using scipy is avaliable [here](http://joepython.googlecode.com/svn-history/r20/trunk/joepython/scipystats/examples/regression/garch.py).

Comment: let me rephrase the question..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an implementation of this in the Python statsmodels library. The source code is available [here](https://github.com/statsmodels/statsmodels/blob/5931ec43c72373ed810c1305b87abf025f867306/statsmodels/sandbox/tsa/garch.py).

Answer (score 2):

There is also [ARCH models in Python](https://github.com/bashtage/arch/)